# How to Inserting Unicode data In MySQL Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql, asp.net, stored-procedures

I have created an application. Used Visual Studio 2010 for the frontend and backend is MySQL 5.3 version. In this application I am using stored procedures in MySQL. I am inserting data in English and it works. But I am inserting Unicode date (like Marathi or Hindi) with the same stored procedure then an error is generated:

> Incorrect string value: '\xE0\xA4\x90 \xE0\xA4...' for column 'p_hindicontent' at row 1

Please help me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Well, you need to ***SHOW US*** something! Show us the stored procedure, and the code that calls it. We can't read your screen - nor your mind - you'll have to show us here....

Comment: Does that string begin with a "[ऐ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0910/index.htm)" character?  If so, the strings you're sending to MySQL are encoded with UTF-8—but MySQL thinks that they are encoded with some other character set; you must set the [character set of the database connection](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-connection.html) correctly.  We will need to see how you're connecting to MySQL to advise further.

Answer (score 4):

you have to write the stored procedure like this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `cn_marathidata`.
`SPemp`
$$
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@
`localhost`
PROCEDURE `SPemp` ( in P_name text charset utf8, in P_address text charset utf8)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Employee
  (
    name,
    address

  )
VALUES
  (
    P_name,
    P_address
  );
END $$

DELIMITER;
```

Hope this tip helps you

Comment: Yes, thats right! Because of the bug https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=13909 it is necessary to explicitly specify a character set for parameters, result and may by local variables as well.

Comment: utf8mb4 helped me